# How to check if entry is file or directory with Net::SFTP and Ruby

Tags: ruby, sftp

Using `Net::SFTP` and `dir` Im trying to determine which entries are files vs directories.  Not sure what to check here:

```
Net::SFTP.start(server_ip, ftp_username, :password => ftp_password, :port => ssh_port, :timeout => 6) do |sftp|
        files = sftp.dir.entries(path).select{|entry| ??? }
        directories = sftp.dir.entries(path).select{|entry| ??? }
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

You can use :

```
files, directories = sftp.dir.entries(path).partition{ |entry| entry.file? }
```

## Example

```
p files.map(&:name)
# ["Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock", ".gitignore", "README.rdoc", "Rakefile", "sftp_pv.expect", "config.ru"]
p directories.map(&:name)
# ["data", "config", "..", "app", "tmp", "public", "vendor", "test", ".git", ".", "log", "bin", "lib", "db"]
```

## How to find the solution?

I copied your code, defined all the needed variables to connect to a personal server, and defined `path` to a remote Rails project.

I changed your block to `p sftp.dir.entries(path).first`

This came out :

```
#<Net::SFTP::Protocol::V01::Name:0x00000000dbf3f8 @name="data", @longname="drwxr-xr-x    2 dev      dev         20480 Oct 27 10:45 data", @attributes=#<Net::SFTP::Protocol::V01::Attributes:0x00000000dbf5b0 @attributes={:size=>20480, :uid=>1002, :gid=>1003, :permissions=>16877, :atime=>1482015468, :mtime=>1477557907}>>
```

Googling `Net::SFTP::Protocol::V01::Name` brough me to the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/net-sftp/Net/SFTP/Protocol/V01/Name).

[`directory?`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/net-sftp/Net/SFTP/Protocol/V01/Name#directory%3F-instance_method) and [`file?`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/net-sftp/Net/SFTP/Protocol/V01/Name#file%3F-instance_method) are promising names!

This :

`p sftp.dir.entries(path).first.file?`

returned `false`.

Finally, I remembered that using `reject` and `select` with the same block could be shortened with [`partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) :

> Returns two arrays, the first containing the elements of enum for
>   which the block evaluates to true, the second containing the rest.